# SQL Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, sql, database

I have made a registration form that was previously working fine, however after some changes in my code I have error "Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$db_name= "login_stock";
$pass= "usbw";

$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("login_stock", $con);
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); //This value has to be the same as in the HTML form file
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); //This value has to be the same as in the HTML form file
$sql="INSERT INTO member_login (id,Name,Password, Allowance) VALUES (NULL,'$name','$password, 100000')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "The form data was successfully added to your database.";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

id within the database is an auto incrementing int and a primary key. However the user is not required to enter their ID when they register.

What is considered the best way to fix this error!

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than an erroneous `'`, you could just drop `id` from the column list:

```
INSERT INTO member_login (Name,Password, Allowance) VALUES ('$name','$password', 100000)
```

You should stop using `mysql_` functions and use prepared statements to prevent against SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you Fresh! :) much appreciated. Such a simple mistake, makes me look some what silly -_- Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO member_login (id,Name,Password, Allowance) 
VALUES (NULL,'$name','$password, 100000');
```

...only has 3 values (the third being the string `'$password, 100000'`). What you mean is probably to quote the password only;

```
INSERT INTO member_login (id,Name,Password, Allowance) 
VALUES (NULL,'$name','$password', 100000);
```

Comment: Thank you for also answering my comment Joachim :)